# validate only a record that is not linked to another of the same type

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, lookup-field

I have a situation:

In the order object I have two types of records: Sales order and Bonus order.

In the layout of the bonus order there is the Origin order lookup field, I can only link a sales order and it cannot be linked to another bonus order.

Can I do this with validation rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely could, though a better tool for this would almost certainly be [a lookup filter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_lookup_filters.htm&type=5).

Stopping people from entering bad data is usually preferable to letting them enter it and then giving them an error (from a validation rule).

Comment: Thanks!

I was able to filter by record type.

so how do I determine that the record linked in the lookup field is already linked to another record?

The sales order can only have one bonus order. If the user creates another bonus request and tries to link it, it needs to give an error. But I can't get through the filter.

Should I use flow?